# Random NoHttpResponseException with ChromeDriver in Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

Google made an update to Chrome over the weekend and I am trying to run some automated tests using Selenium. Ever since the update, every few 5 or 6 runs results in the following error. I run the test immediately again and it works fine. It's just really annoying because it breaks randomly.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
Build info: version: '2.6.0', revision: '13840', time: '2011-09-13 16:51:41'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeCommandExecutor.execute(ChromeCommandExecutor.java:59)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:377)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:182)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:199)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:210)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:174)
at com.core.FindElementAndWait.apply(FindElementAndWait.java:28)
at com.core.FindElementAndWait.apply(FindElementAndWait.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:173)
    ... 68 more
```

Comment: Have you eliminated the possibility of it being a coincidence and having nothing to do with chrome update by running your tests against a different browser to see if the same thing happens?

Comment: I have not run this against a different browser because the application is currently only built for chrome. However, I have run this several times against the previous version of chrome with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a fix for this bug, but it's not been released yet.  There's a workaround at https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2513 and if you track that issue, you will be notified of the fix's progress.

Comment: Be careful with "it's not been released yet" - that's going to sound odd to someone reading the answer in 2 years time.

Answer (score 0):

We have seen the same problem with ChromeDriver. The solution in our case was to add a `Thread.sleep(1)` between each and every call to the selenium RC API.

For some reason, it solved the issue.